# Age range computation where each country has at least two distinct ages of the individuals

Tags: mysql, sql

For my dataset here, I want to create result such that for those countries (which have at least two distinct Ages), I could summarise the Age Range.

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
    ID int (3) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    Age int (3) NOT NULL,
    Nationality varchar (50) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO Employees 
    (ID, Name, Age, Nationality)
VALUES
    (1, 'CHIN YEN', '19', 'China'),
    (2, 'MIKE PEARL', '21', 'United Kingdom'),
    (3, 'GREEN FIELD', '45', 'Nethernalnds'),
    (4, 'DEWANE PAUL', '57', 'Canada'),
    (5, 'MATTS', '32', 'Australia'),
    (6, 'PLANK OTO', '51', 'France'),
    (7, 'Manish Kumar', '42', 'India'),
    (8, 'Matts', '55', 'USA'),
    (9, 'Mahesh Kumar', '32', 'USA'),
    (10, 'Chin Yen', '21', 'Japan');
```

And what I was trying to do is:

```
SELECT Nationality,
       Max(Age) - Min(Age) AS Age_Range
FROM Employees;
```

Comment: You don't really store age, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a query which will return age range for only those countries in which at least two individuals with distinct non-zero ages exist, following can be approach.

```
SELECT Nationality,
       Max(Age) - Min(NULLIF(Age,0)) AS Age_Range
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Nationality
having Max(Age) - Min(NULLIF(Age,0)) > 0
```

what is does is that for any individual has `age=0` , `nullif` convert its age into `NULL` which is then ignored by aggregate function `MIN`.

I have changed the data you shared as below.

```
INSERT INTO Employees 
    (ID, Name, Age, Nationality)
VALUES
    (1, 'CHIN YEN', 0, 'United Kingdom'),
    (2, 'MIKE PEARL', 21, 'United Kingdom'),
    (3, 'GREEN FIELD', 45, 'Nethernalnds'),
    (4, 'DEWANE PAUL', 57, 'Nethernalnds'),
    (5, 'MATTS', 0, 'Nethernalnds'),
    (6, 'PLANK OTO', 51, 'France'),
    (7, 'Manish Kumar', 42, 'India'),
    (8, 'Matts', 55, 'USA'),
    (9, 'Mahesh Kumar', 32, 'USA'),
    (10, 'Chin Yen', 21, 'Japan');
```

Below is the result as expected using the query i shared.

[image]

You can check DEMO [here](http://rextester.com/HXYRU86169)

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need a `group by`:

```
SELECT Nationality,
       Max(Age) - Min(Age) AS Age_Range
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Nationality;
```

You might want to add `HAVING Age_Range > 0`.

Comment: I just wonder why I should use `Having Age_Range > 0` Can't I run a quecry to check whether or not a Nationality has at least two individuals with distinct non-zero ages?

Comment: An age range of 0 is not the same thing as only having one record - you could have two records with the same age, however the title of the question states you only require records with at least 2 distinct (i.e. different) ages. If this is *not* the case then add `having count(*) >1)`

Comment: @symcbean . . . It is the same when the OP clearly states:  "which have at least two distinct Ages".